# SSAS Dimension relationship

Tags: sql-server, ssas, dimension

I have two dimension.

one is Manufacturer

[image]

Other is Supplier.

[image]

Have a fact table.

[image]

Need to query the sales amount using supplier code, also want to see the relation between Supplier and Manufacturer against sales amount.
Can this be done.

Is there any possibilities that can be achieved without adding a supplier key to fact.

Please help!!!

Comment: Why are you against adding the supplier key to the fact? That would be your easiest and probably best solution. Also, it looks like you have a many:many between supplier and manufacturer based upon the codes, but you have different keys on the supplier that make me think it's really just one: many for supplier: manufacturer. Can you confirm?

Comment: Its an hard way to identify which manufacturer key belongs to which supplier, tats stopping me to add key in fact. Its a many to many relationship, one manufacturer can have multiple supplier, a supplier can be part of multiple manufacturer. Any possibility without adding keys..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot query sales amount using supplier code because the manufacturer(int)|Amount($) pair doesn't uniquely identify supplier.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of **Snowflake Schema (Dimension) Design**

For now, you might me having Manufacture as a dimension, you can still achieve this

SELECT [Measures].[Amount] ON 0,
               
{[DimManufacture].[SupplierCode].MEMBERS,
               
[DimManufacture].[Manufacture Code].MEMBERS
} ON 1
                     FROM [Cube Name]

As of i understand, i guess this is what you are looking for.